# make new aws ec2 join same IP Range (say 1.2.3.x)

Tags: amazon-web-services

Everytime I create a new EC2 machine on AWS, it got a new random IPv4 public IP. 
I work behind a firewall that only allow me to go to some very limited IP range, 
So how could I setting in my AWS account or setting in my EC2 configuration to make it join a range IP (let say 1.2.3.x) 
Regards, LongNX.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it manually, during the launch of your EC2 instance(s). When you get to the step to configure instance details, select the desired VPC and subnet .

If the existing subnets are not allowed on your firewall, you can create a subnet using the IP addresses you want (if these IPs are included in the CIDR that was selected during your VPC creation). Otherwise you need to create another VPC with IP addresses that include your desired ones (allowed on firewall).